# Kubuntu 18.10 libqt5core5a update issues

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, kubuntu

I want a solution to a problem I am facing regarding *libqt5core5a* updates on my machine. Whenever I try do the update, either via Discover, Muon, or Konsole, I get the following error

```
"E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"
```

at the end of my string. This happens when I try run the update directly as well via `sudo apt-get install`. Please see below for full details (Konsole script):

```
Need to get 0 B/2,050 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

(Reading database ... 270556 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libqt5core5a_5.11.1+dfsg-7ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5core5a:amd64 (5.11.1+dfsg-7ubuntu3) over (5.11.1+dfsg-7ubuntu1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libqt5core5a_5.11.1+dfsg-7ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.11.1' to '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.11.1.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libqt5core5a_5.11.1+dfsg-7ubuntu3_amd64.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: It looks like it's not downloaded, but coming from your local system and is corrupt.  I'd suggest deleting it and allowing it to be re-downloaded. If you're not using the main archive, I'd also check the health of your mirror (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) and possibly selecting a more reliable/up-to-date one; but it's possible the file was corrupted by a bad download (aborted before completion) or post-download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove broken "downladed" package with

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libqt5core5a_5.11.1+dfsg-7ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

or remove all downloaded packages with

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

and then resume upgrade process

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly.